# Windows-10 LoadLibraryA fails with error 126

Tags: visual-c++, dll, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

My application calls LoadLibraryA to dynamically load a dll. This works perfectly fine on **Windows-7** with **VS-2013** but errors out on **Windows-10(UWP)** with **VS-2015**. 

 The app is written in Java which tries to load our native dll(written in C++)

On Windows-10 I get error **126** from **GetLastError()**

> The specified module could not be found

I do not see any issue in the dll path specified to the LoadLibraryA function as the very same path works as expected in Windows-7.

Seems like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is unavailable for Windows-10. Again I do not suspect any issue with dependencies as loading dll is working without errors on my Windows-7

Comment: What's the library you're trying to load? Not all system DLLs that are available on Windows are available on UWP. Windows 7 != Windows 10(UWP)

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, Thanks for the response. I am trying to load our native library written in C++. The app can be created in any high level language like Java/C#. In this particular case though, my app code is written in Java which is trying to load our dll (native code written in C++). I forgot to mention this detail. Let me add this to the original question itself.

Comment: So what native system libraries does your DLL load? Read my first comment again - what happens on Windows 7 is irrelevant, because Windows 10 UWP is not Windows 7. If you can't determine what DLLs your own DLL is loading, and you have the ability to use DW on WIndows 7 to figure it out, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: I'm running dependency walker in windows 10 right now. What makes you think it isn't available for windows 10? Surely you didn't read "Download Version 2.2.6000 for x86 (Windows 95 / 98 / Me / NT / 2000 / XP / 2003 / Vista / 7 / 8) [610k]" and then not even try it.  

This is still the first step for debugging any problem with LoadLibrary